# Are CTRL+C and <esc> the same?

Tags: macvim

I tried entering the key sequence `<esc>+<n>+i+<some-char>+<esc>` and it'll type `<some-char>` `<n>` times.

But if I'm using a macbook keyboard there is no escape key, so I tried this instead `<CTRL+C>+<n>+i+<some-char>+<CTRL+C>`, and it didn't type `<some-char>` `<n>` times; is there an alternative way to do this on a Macbook, or when you don't have an esc key?

Comment: Wdym no escape key? Is this a macbook with a touchbar? There is an esc on the touchbar, afaik

Comment: I'm not talking about a particular Macbook.  I had one some years ago from work and it didn't have an esc key and drove me nuts!

Comment: Mine has esc. Thats bizarre. Ctrl-C cancels sometimes, cancelling the effects of some operations

Comment: Ah wait sorry, now I remember, it was a MacBook Air.  And that was a MacBook Error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<esc>` and `<C-c>` are mostly similar.

They will differ in some cases such as the following:

- Doing a vertical insert (`<C-v>`, then going down, then `i` to insert the same character, or text, on multiple lines): `<esc>` will leave the insert mode and insert the typed text on the selected lines, whereas `<C-c>` will leave the insert mode and will only insert the text where the cursor was (cancelling the vertical insert).
- When using `input()`, the behaviour changes, cf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56163617/3866623
- `<n>i`, as in your question, `esc` will insert `n` times what you typed, `<C-c>` will cancel the input and insert it once.

`<C-c>` is pretty much cancelling the action and going back in Normal mode.

If you want an alternative to `<esc>`, `<C-[>` (`CTRL-[`) is doing exactly the same, in case you don't have an escape key.

For reference, `:help i_CTRL-[` and `:help i_CTRL-C`:

```
<Esc> or CTRL-[    End insert or Replace mode, go back to Normal mode. Finish 
                   abbreviation.                                                   
                   Note: If your <Esc> key is hard to hit on your keyboard, 
                   train yourself to use CTRL-[. If Esc doesn't work and you 
                   are using a Mac, try CTRL-Esc. Or disable Listening under
                   Accessibility preferences.

CTRL-C             Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for     
                   abbreviations.  Does not trigger the InsertLeave autocommand    
                   event.
```